# windows service to Desktop Application communication

Tags: c++, windows-services, window, screensharing

I'm new to programming. There are quite a lot of Q/A on this, but I couldn't find a concrete answer. Hence the question. I'm writing a screen sharing application. Now I want to turn that application to windows service. which I already did with. Apparently, the application works like this. When the counter party sends the screenshots, the application receives it and parses the data to RGB and shows on a window renderer. Because now its a service, although it receives the data, i believe that it may not be able to open renderer in the current desktop due to session isolation, the way to get around this would be to use IPC between Desktop App an the service. However, it makes it complected. Is there any simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: There is a flag that can be set that allows services to interact with the desktop (like putting up windows). However, you might want to think about if you really want this as a service, or if it's enough to run as a startup-folder program?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but couldn't succeed. The reason I want to go for services is that, i want to capture the logon/logoff desktops when the system boots up and shuts down. Most of them say its not possible to capture the logon screen. But, I could do that in Admin account and some elevated permissions through PS tools.